# Ubuntu Touch - Editing Contact Details

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, contacts

How do I edit a contacts details (e.g. mobile number) to show it is a UK or another country number?

I can see what country it is from the prefix code, but in the mobile number section I can only select from a pre-set selection and when I select "Other" I cannot add UK.

I have contacts who have a sim for Australia and the UK and want to distinguish which is which in my contact details.

Comment: I have raised this in launchpad - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/contacts/+bug/1664089